# jQuery CSS - don't select <img> tag inside <a> tag

Tags: jquery, css

I have some jQuery code which selects all `<a>` tags in my site that start with "http" and adds either a generic icon or that site's favicon and works perfectly.
My problem is that sometimes the `<a>` tag surrounds an `<img>` tag, and I don't want it to select those, so how do I tell jQuery that? Do I somehow use `:not()`?

Here's the current jQuery code:

```
$("#bodyCopy a[href^='http']").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        background: "url(http://g.etfv.co/" + this.href + ") left center no-repeat",
        "padding-left": "20px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#bodyCopy a[href^='http']").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).find("img").length < 1 ) {  // Count <img> children
        // Continue only if fewer than one <img> within <a>
        $(this).css({
            background: "url(http://g.etfv.co/" + this.href + ") left center no-repeat",
            "padding-left": "20px"
        });
    }
});
```